# Passing value in Mock Rhino test

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have following code:

```
if (ActiveApplication.GetField("previous_date").Value != ActiveApplication.GetField("new_date").Value)
{
        //do something.. 
}
```

I want to unit test this. Being new to Rhino tests, I am trying to figure out how to pass value so that i go in the loop. Here is what i have tried:

```
var previous_date = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IField>();
stubApplication.Stub(x => x.GetField("previous_date")).Return(previous_date);
previous_date.Stub(x => x.GetInternalValue()).Return("20160525");

var new_date = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IField>();
stubApplication.Stub(x => x.GetField("new_date")).Return(new_date);
new_date.Stub(x => x.GetInternalValue()).Return("20160525");
```

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns previous_date, an interface of type `IField`:

```
stubApplication.Stub(x => x.GetField("previous_date")).Return(previous_date)
```

Because it's not a base class implementation, your code uses the `Value` property on the interface which has to be setup in a mock as well, rather than using `GetInternalValue()`.  Same with `new_stub`.

**EDIT:** You need essentially to do the following (note I'm not sure if this is the correct syntax as I haven't used that framework, but I'm trying to capture the essence):

```
previous_date.Stub(x => x.Value).Return("20160525");
```

Comment: That is what i did above right? But it is not working?

Comment: Not the Value property.  You need something like (I don't know the exact syntax): `previous_date.Stub(x => x.Value).Return("20160525");`; that is not in the above code sample.